# how can i tell how much RAM the site needs?

Tags: windows, shared-hosting

session on shared hosting is too short and the company owning the host is asking what is the memory requirements for the CMS

how can that be checked?
and what is a average for CMS system?

Answer (score 1):

A some what naive approach would be to monitor the IIS processes on a developer machine with N amount of visitors and No users.. And then use a formula somewhat similair to:

```
Total needed RAM =  DevRam_NoUser + (DevRam-DevRam_NoUser)/N * TargetNrUsers
```

Where DevRam_NoUser is memory usage when there is no users online (in practice: use the system for a while and then let it "rest").
DevRam is the amount of memory used with N sim. users exciting the CMS.

Edit:
And, probably a lot more *safe* way is to actually measure the entire systems memory usage (remove the difference from startup tho). But it will not be as accurate and it will depend alot on system parameters that may fluctuate between your developer machine and the targetted server.

Also; Don't forget any external processes aswell that needs to be calculated for; SQL etc. This you will get for "free" but will alot of noise to your measurements if you measure the entire systems memory, so If you go for this approach: Do alot of tests!